# How do I show or hide buttons based on certain cell criteria in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Quite new to excel and VBA....I want to hide certain buttons on my excel sheet based on if a reference cell is empty or not. So the button should show if the reference cell contains any value, and should not be visible if the reference cell is empty. When I run my code, I get a Run-time error : Object doesn't support this property or method. I have renamed all of my buttons on my sheet. I'm not sure what the problem is. See code below....

```
Sub hideshowcheckboxes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Dispatch TOOL").Select
If Range("D12").Value = " " Then
    Sheets("Dispatch TOOL").check1.Visible = False
Else
    Sheets("Dispatch TOOL").check1.Visible = True
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you use an ActiveX Object for a checkbox or a Form Control? For ActiveX your code should work... so i supect you are using a form control

Comment: I have used a form control

Comment: Ok. I assumed that the line you get the error on was the one with the checkbox. You didn't specify. Please advise if my assumption is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of CheckBox Control that you use matters. To use a form control use the second approach.

```
Sub test()

'ActiveX Object
Sheet1.CheckBox1.Visible = True

'Form Control Object
Sheet1.Shapes("Check Box 2").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: hi angie. glad it was the solution to you problem. If the answer solved your problem you can also set the check mark so that others know this question is solved. thanks!